# Rowspan "clean-up" algorithm

Tags: algorithm, html-table

I have a structure, that resembles HTML table's colspan/rowspan feature:

```
[
 [1,4], [4,1]
 [2,2], [2,2]
 [1,1], [1,1], [1,1], [1,1]
]
```

is like

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan=4></td>
  <td colspan=4></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=2 colspan=2></td>
  <td colspan=2 rowspan=2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>

----------------
|  |           |
|  |-----------|
|  |     |     |
|  |-----------|
|  |  |  |  |  |
----------------
```

The second row (and the first cell from the first row, that spans all 4 rows) in

```
[
 [1,3], [4,1]
 [2,1], [2,1]
 [1,1], [1,1], [1,1], [1,1]
]
```

and "topology" of the table remains the same

However a table like

```
[
 [1,4], [4,1]
 [2,2], [2,1]
 [2,1],
 [1,1], [1,1], [1,1], [1,1]
]

----------------
|  |           |
|  |-----------|
|  |     |     |
|  |     |-----|
|  |     |     |
|  |-----------|
|  |  |  |  |  |
----------------
```

is not "collapsible"

What is an effecient algorithm to perform this transformation or leave the table as is? Any programming language would work.

Assume, that the structure is valid (not missing cells, the table is rectangular) if it simplifies the task

Comment: Very nicely laid out question...but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand the collapsing operation you mention. Could you please give a more detailed example?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the cell extents to coordinates.

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5
0 ----------------
  |  |           |
1 |  |-----------|
  |  |     |     |
  |  |     |     |
  |  |     |     |
3 |  |-----------|
  |  |  |  |  |  |
4 ----------------
```

Compute the sorted set of y-coordinates (`0, 1, 3, 4`). Map each coordinate to its index in the set (`0: 0, 1: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3`).

Compute the sorted set of x-coordinates (`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`). Map each coordinate to its index in the set (identity map).

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5
0 ----------------
  |  |           |
1 |  |-----------|
  |  |     |     |
  |  |     |     |
  |  |     |     |
2 |  |-----------|
  |  |  |  |  |  |
3 ----------------
```

Convert the cell coordinates back to extents.